# Making a nested for loop into a single for loop

Tags: java, for-loop, nested-loops

I had an assignment to create an array of random number from 10-100.
Then I need to sout all the numbers not listed in the array. 
I did the assignment with a nested for loops, to cross reference the arrays, then I changed all the found numbers in the array into -1. Finally I printed out the elements in the array that were not -1.
My professor told me that is it possible for me to do this assignment with only one for loop and there is no need to do a nested for loop. and make the computer run 10,000 times instead of just 100.
Is that possible? If so how?

Thank you.

```
    package assignment.pkg1;

    import java.util.Random;
    public class Assignment1 {

       static Random ran = new Random();

        public static void main(String[] args) {

            int[] arr = new int[100];

            for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
                arr[i] = (ran.nextInt(90)) + 10;
            }

            InversingArray(arr);


        }

        public static void InversingArray(int[] randomArray) {

            int[] fullArray = new int[100];

           for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
                fullArray[i] = i;
            }

            for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
                for (int j = 1; j < 100; j++) {

                    if (randomArray[j] == fullArray[i]) {
                        fullArray[i] = -1;

                    }
                }
           }
            System.out.println("These numbers are not in randomArray: ");
             for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
                if (fullArray[i] != -1) {
                    System.out.println(fullArray[i]);
                }

            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

In your code you create an array to hold the possible values.  If you think about it, the array index will always be equal to the number stored in the array.

`fullArray[i] = i;`

This is redundant.

What you are being asked to do is determine which numbers have been used: a boolean test.  This means that you should have an array of boolean that is initially false (the default value of booleans in java) and is flipped to true when an equal integer is flipped to true.

Something like

```
int[] arr = new int[100];

for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
        arr[i] = (ran.nextInt(90)) + 10;
}

// ba starts with all false values 
boolean ba[] == new boolean[90];  // note that the instructor said 10-100
for(int i=0; i<90; i++) {
  ba[arr[i]] = true;
  // lets assume arr[0] == 45
  // ba[arr[0]] is the same as ba[45]
  // ba[45] = true;  will set that bucket of the boolean array to true 
}

System.out.println("These numbers are not in randomArray: ");
for (int k = 0; k < 10; k++) {
    System.out.println(k);
}
for (int j = 0; j < 90; j++) {
    if (!ba[j]) { // shorthand for ba[j]==false
        System.out.println(j+10); // The array starts at a base of 10
    }
}
```

Be aware (probably the point of the exercise) that you are working with an array [0..90] that represents the numbers [10..100].

Comment: but how would get rid of the nested for loop? Wouldn't I still need to cross reference every ba[i] with every randomArray[i]?

Comment: No,  A pass through the array to set the corresponding boolean value for each item.  I''l put some comments in that should help.

Comment: Ok thank you very much, also he wants us to print out all values that arnt in the array between 0-100, so 0-9 are obviously included

Comment: That is a specific dependent on your instructor.  Post as another question and someone should be able to help.

Comment: Using an array index from 0 - 89, but indexing into it using numbers that have values from 10 - 99, guarantees array index exceptions. Easiest fix: make `ba[] = new boolean[100]`. Bonus: it automatically accounts for 0-9.

Comment: Fair point.  I wasn't going for robust :) or elegant for that matter.  More trying to explain the relationship between the counted and the count.

Comment: Ok, but a solution that throws exceptions instead of running doesn't communicate that relationship nearly as well as one that runs. And it's a simple edit. Not throwing rocks _per se_, just want it to work.

Answer (score 0):

The nested loop currently looks like this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
    for (int j = 1; j < 100; j++) {
        if (randomArray[j] == fullArray[i]) {
            fullArray[i] = -1;
        }
    }
}
```

But we know, that **`fullArray[i]` is always the same as `i`**.

So you can rewrite it to:

```
for (int j = 1; j < 100; j++) {
    int i = randomArray[j];
    fullArray[i] = -1;
}
```

Or even shorter:

```
for (int j = 1; j < 100; j++) {
    fullArray[randomArray[j]] = -1;
}
```